# System.OutOfMemoryException SQL Server 2012 and 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, memory

I have a 64-bit and 64gb memory for both SQL Server 2012 and 2008R2, when I generate a report w/c has 900K rows, it finished the query smoothly and no problem, but when I'm going to copy the result with header. The error System.OutOfMemoryException is prompting. What do you think causes this problem?

Comment: This is a limitation on your client OS' ability to have that much data in the clipboard (it may be exceeding SSMS' ability to copy data *to* the clipboard, but the difference is ultimately negligible). So, my recommendation would be: stop doing that, and send the results to a file instead. Are you planning to paste 50+ GB worth of data from the output grid of SSMS into, what, a spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank you @Aaron, the file size is like about 200mb when I try to manualy paste it to spreadsheet

Comment: How are you able to manually paste it to a spreadsheet? In any case, the amount of raw data that SSMS is trying to copy is not necessarily going to be in the same universe as the size of a file Excel can shrink a spreadsheet to...

Comment: I'm not the one who actually made that, I think he save the result as CSV or text file and manually place it to spreadsheet. But is there a way to prevent that error?

Comment: Yes, choose results to file instead of results to grid, then open up the resulting .rpt file in Excel. Also find out what the other person *actually* did. It might not be what you think.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron but our customers demand is to do it using copy with header :( But I'll suggest that. Thank you!

Comment: if only microsoft packaged a free reporting tool that allowed users to save/export query results as csv/text/excel. perhaps one of these days they'll see the light. i'd suggest that they name it "sql server reporting services" so that people could clearly identify its function

Comment: Or Excel with PowerPivot, Excel with External Data Sources. SSMS Results to File, BCP, [PowerShell](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/03/powershell-export-query-to-csv.html), sqlcmd etc

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is a memory limitation on the machine running Management studio. We have this problem some times when the client laptop only has 2GB-4GB of RAM. You could use the Export data function in Management Studio or the SQL Server "bcp Utility"

SQL Server Export Wizard: Right-Click on the Database > Tasks > Export Data
[image: Export Data Help]

Bulk copy utility (bcp): Below is the sample syntax that we use and also links to the Microsoft documentation, note that xp_cmdshell needs to be enabled.
Sample syntax (all one line): 
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp mydatabase.dbo.mytable out C:\Myfolder\MyFile.csv -c -t, -T -S ServerName\InstanceName'

Microsoft Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx